# XMLHttpRequest() response is empty in Edge but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, response

I use the following function to load a large file (+500mb); I am not able to split this file because it is provided by another entity and the file content is very hard to split into smaller chunks;

The resonse is filled with the content of the file if I am using Firefox, however if I use the same function with the same file in Edge the response is empty;
readystate is 4 and status is 200 but the response is empty;

I also used the fetch API and the result is the same; no content in response;

```
function loadFile(url, ok, err) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.overrideMimeType('text/plain');
        request.open('GET', url + (/\?/.test(url) ? '&' : '?') + new Date().getTime(), true);
        request.addEventListener(
            'load',
            function (event) {
                var response = event.target.response;
                if (this.status === 200) {
                    if (ok) {
                        ok(response);
                    }
                } else if (this.status === 0) {
                    // Some browsers return HTTP Status 0 when using non-http protocol
                    // e.g. 'file://' or 'data://'. Handle as success.
                    console.warn('loadFile: HTTP Status 0 received.');
                    if (ok) {
                        ok(response);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (err) {
                        err(event);
                    }
                }
            },
            false
        );

        request.addEventListener(
            'error',
            function (event) {
                if (err) {
                    err(event);
                }
            },
            false
        );
        request.send(null);
    }
```

Comment: Did you detect the empty response on DevTools' Network tab, or only in JS code?

Comment: i can see the loading of the file the Network tab, and the content-length is right, but in javascript if i want to access the value it says length = 0

Comment: OK, how about the actual content tab, is there anything in Edge?

Comment: yes eveything there like expected; little example can be found here https://github.com/mhoelzner/edge_large_file_error; only thing need to be added is a file larger than 500mb

Comment: one thing to mention also, it worked until around april this year, since then this error occures

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of the XMLHttp class. My suggestion is to use streams and fetch api.
Check the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream/getReader